# Is real time event monitoring captures the User Session Activities,Page rendering time,Single page Request/response time

Tags: apex, lightning-events, eventlogfile, event-monitoring

We are planning to implement real time monitoring for event tracking,but not sure if below details are getting captured or not

**User Session Activities**-What action user has performed in that session
**Page rendering time**
**responsiveness of the application**-Like each time when user loged in to salesforce,how much time it took to open salesforce app.

Answer (score 0):

Real-Time Event Monitoring based LightningURIEvent and EventLogFile based Lightning Events capture information about what a user does and a session key is tied to the events.

I would also use the lightning events to measure EPT (effective page time) to figure out how much time it took for various pages to load.